# How to visualize 3d joints of a SMPL model based on pose params

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am trying to use `demo.py` in [nkolot
/
GraphCMR | GitHub](https://github.com/nkolot/GraphCMR). I am interested in obtaining joints from the inferred [SMPL](https://smpl.is.tue.mpg.de/) image and visualize it similar to described in README of this project: [gulvarol
/
smplpytorch | GitHub](https://github.com/gulvarol/smplpytorch).

I also posted the issue here: https://github.com/nkolot/GraphCMR/issues/36.

#### What I tried that didn't work.

I changed https://github.com/nkolot/GraphCMR/blob/4e57dca4e9da305df99383ea6312e2b3de78c321/demo.py#L118 to
`pred_vertices, pred_vertices_smpl, pred_camera, smpl_pose, smpl_shape = model(...)` to get `smpl_pose` (of shape `torch.Size([1, 24, 3, 3])`). Then I just flattened it by doing `smpl_pose.cpu().data.numpy()[:, :, :, -1].flatten('C').reshape(1, -1)` and used the resulting `(1, 72)` pose params as input in [pose_params variable of smplpytorch demo](https://github.com/gulvarol/smplpytorch/blob/a18b0197d8a7204865b2ec95307e2286533f9487/demo.py#L18).

The resulting visualization doesn't look correct to me. Is this the right approach? Perhaps there is an easier way to do what I am doing.
[How to get 3d joints from demo.py and visualize it | nkolot
/
GraphCMR](https://github.com/nkolot/GraphCMR/issues/36)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
smpl_pose (of shape torch.Size([1, 24, 3, 3]))
```

is the SMPL pose parameters expressed as a **rotation matrix**.
You need to make a transformation from **rotation matrix** to **axis-angle representation** which is (72,1). You can use Rodrigues formula to do it, as claimed in the paper:

[image]

Get more information from the paper:
[SMPL: A Skinned Multi-Person Linear Model](https://virtualhumans.mpi-inf.mpg.de/papers/SMPL15/SMPL15.pdf)